# Python - Saving multiple figures to individual files with a function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm pretty new to Python and am experiencing some issues while using pyplot in part of a larger program. I am passing a list (which is taken from a column of a csv) to a function which is to plot a histogram and save it to file. Here is the function:

```
def plot_hist(column_list):
    """Plots a histogram from column data passed as a list"""
    global display_count
    display_count += 1
    plt.hist = plt.hist(column_list, len(column_list), density=True, facecolor='b', alpha=0.75)
    plt.grid(True)
    fig = plt
    fig.savefig(f'../wk5/display{display_count}.png')
```

I can successfully save one image to file before experiencing "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable". The error itself occurs at
`lt.hist = plt.hist(column_list, len(column_list), density=True, facecolor='b', alpha=0.75)` I also have tried closing the plt and calling .clf() on the fig. Like I said, i'm pretty green to python and hope it's not a stupid mistake. I appreciate any help!

Comment: In which line did you get this error? The code you have posted seems ok to me.. could you add more information by editing the question

Comment: plt.hist = plt.hist(column_list, len(column_list), density=True, facecolor='b', alpha=0.75) is the line in which the error occurs, but mind you, it only happens after one display img is already saved.

Comment: _"[I] hope it's not a stupid mistake"_ Oh well, it's a stupid mistake… `plt.hist = plt.hist(...` means that you overwrite the method `plt.hist` with the tuple of diverse data that the first invocation of the method returns.  Also, later, `fig = plt` is a little bit meaningless, it means "From now, `fig` is an alias for the `matplotlib.pyplot` module"

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. I'll good off of that and I'll post below if it's fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the input from [gboffi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2749397/gboffi), I got rid of some useless assignments and it works like a charm.

```
def plot_hist(column_list):
    """Plots a histogram from column data passed as a list"""
    global display_count
    display_count += 1
    plt.hist(column_list, len(column_list), density=True, facecolor='b', alpha=0.75)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig(f'../wk5/display{display_count}.png')
```